# How to break while loop in Android Studio while sending message

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, sms, smsmanager

I have a chat application. I have to send a message only once whereas I am using while(true). Because of this loop message is sending again and again. How can I break the while loop when the message is sent only once? That message should not be sent again and again.

Here is my code:

```
while (true) {
    String[] jobsNumbers = numbers.toArray(new String[numbers.size()]);
    new SendMessage().execute(jobsNumbers);
}
```

and here is my sendMessage Asynctask:

```
private class sendMessage extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
   protected Integer doInBackground(String[] toNumbers) {
       totalNumbers = toNumbers.length;
       for (i = 0; i < toNumbers.length; i++) {
           toNumber = toNumbers[i];
           if (countMessagePerDay() >= Integer.parseInt(MaxNoOfMessagePerDay)) {
               try {
                   Thread.sleep(10000);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           } else {
               sendSMS(toNumber);
               this.publishProgress(1);
           }

           if (randomNo != 0 && isSent) {
               databaseHelperClass.updateJobMessageStatus(JobId);
              }
       }
    return toNumbers.length;
}
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), i + "/" + totalNumbers + " :: to " + toNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(Integer integer) {
        super.onCancelled(integer);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onPostExecute(integer);
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using the while loop at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break;` for this,like:

```
while (true) {
String[] jobsNumbers = numbers.toArray(new String[numbers.size()]);
new SendMessage().execute(jobsNumbers);
Boolean destroy= true;
 if(destroy == true){
 break;
} 

}
```

Comment: I am using sqlite database. I am getting an arraylist from database which messages are being sent. I am also storing boolean variable isSent in database. Now I want that messages should not be sent again whose Id already had isSent= true. how i can do that?

Comment: you should post another question for that @ansarabbas,more people will know about that

Comment: by the way when you get the arraylist from the database,you should make a query to get the data with isSent= false only

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
while (i<1) 
{
  String[] jobsNumbers = numbers.toArray(new String[numbers.size()]);
  new SendMessage().execute(jobsNumbers);
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the original problem, some explanation of your solution would improve the general usefulness of your answer.